# MySQL multidimensional select from views

Tags: mysql, select, view, multidimensional-array

I would like to display data re-arranged year by year and one of the possible solution is using views and select from them. The data matrix is something like (of course it's a ficticious demo dataset):

```
USA  2005  22  156
CAN  2005  14  101
MEX  2005   5   32
USA  2006  24  160
CAN  2006  16  103
USA  2007  26  163
MEX  2007   8   35
```

The SQL code to create and populate the table is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tab1`;<br>
CREATE TABLE `tab1` ( <br>
  `id1` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `iso3` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `year` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `aaa` int(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
  `bbb` int(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id1`) 
)


INSERT INTO `tab1` VALUES 
('1', 'USA', '2005', '22', '156'),
('2', 'CAN', '2005', '14', '101'), 
('3', 'MEX', '2005', '5', '32'),   
('4', 'USA', '2006', '24', '160'), 
('5', 'CAN', '2006', '16', '103'), 
('6', 'USA', '2007', '26', '163'), 
('7', 'MEX', '2007', '8', '35');   
COMMIT;
```

And now I would like to obtain for parameter 'aaa' a 2D table like this:

```
country 2005 2006 2007 
USA     22   24   26   
CAN     14   16        
MEX      5   8
```

However the following SQL code is omitting all the lines with missing data, be it one single value and I only get one line

```
 USA    22  24  26
```

The SQL code is:

```
 SELECT view2005.Country, view2005.2005, view2006.2006, view2007.2007 
 FROM   view2005, view2006, view2007 
 WHERE  view2005.country = view2006.country 
 AND    view2005.country = view2007.country
```

Any idea how to do it including lines with missing data? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use `JOIN` than implicit JOIN with `WHERE`. Additional advanatge is that you can convert it to a `LEFT JOIN` so data for 2005 that don't have a 2006 related row  (and are not matched) will still be shown.

Use Galz's solution or search as correctly advised for how to create PIVOT queries.

---

One such logic to create a pivot query would be:

```
 SELECT iso3 AS Country
      , SUM(IF(year=2005, aaa, 0)) AS 2005
      , SUM(IF(year=2006, aaa, 0)) AS 2006
      , SUM(IF(year=2007, aaa, 0)) AS 2007 
 FROM  tab1 AS t
 GROUP BY iso3
```

If there are years without any data, you will get `NULL` in that column.
You can use `COALESCE()` function if you want `0` to be shown and not `NULL`:

```
 SELECT iso3 AS Country
      , COALESCE( SUM( IF(year=2004, aaa, 0) ) , 0) AS "2004" 
      , COALESCE( SUM( IF(year=2005, aaa, 0) ) , 0) AS "2005"
      , COALESCE( SUM( IF(year=2006, aaa, 0) ) , 0) AS "2006"
      , COALESCE( SUM( IF(year=2007, aaa, 0) ) , 0) AS "2007" 
 FROM  tab1 AS t
 GROUP BY iso3
```

Comment: What about countries which have no data for 2005?

Answer (score 2):

Use left joins, and a view (or table, or inner select like below) which has all distinct countries:

```
SELECT c.country, view2005.2005, view2006.2006, view2007.2007 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT country FROM tab1) as c
LEFT JOIN view2005 ON view2005.country = c.country
LEFT JOIN view2006 ON view2006.country = c.country
LEFT JOIN view2007 ON view2007.country = c.country
GROUP BY c.country
```

**EDIT:**

In a more general context, what you are asking here is to create a *pivot* of this table, which is a common problem that has common solutions. Here is a nice "How To": http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1339#78

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Galz for the link to pivots and thank you ypercube for the SQL. It worked after enclosing the years into quotes to make them CHAR.

I was further intrigued by the question what happens if I add a row with no values at all or a row out of range of the years so I have added

```
INSERT INTO `tab1` VALUES 
('7', 'ATA', '2004', '', '')
```

The result was that I got a mix of NULL and INT zero values. This is not good because zero is a valid number and legitimate data. So I have modified the query to get exactly the result I need:

```
SELECT iso3 AS countryб
       SUM( IF(year=2004, aaa, NULL) ) AS "2004",
       SUM( IF(year=2005, aaa, NULL) ) AS "2005",
       SUM( IF(year=2006, aaa, NULL) ) AS "2006",
       SUM( IF(year=2007, aaa, NULL) ) AS "2007"
 FROM  tab1
 GROUP BY iso3
```

Comment: You can use `COALESCE()` function if you want `0` to be shown and not `NULL`.